# Working around SwiftUI Path crash in Xcode 11 beta 5

Tags: ios, swiftui

Apple broke `Path` in Xcode 11 beta 5:

> A known issue in Xcode 11 beta 5 causes your app to crash when you use the `Path` structure.

So I'm trying to work around this using `CGMutablePath`:

```
   var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
            return Path(path)
        }
    }
```

This draws a square.

When I try to change the color as follows:

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
            return Path(path).fill(Color.purple)
        }
    }
```

I get:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'GeometryReader<_>' to return type 'some View'
Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type
```

I'm not sure what return type to use? I tried `Path` but evidently `fill` doesn't return another `Path`.

I tried `View` but I get:

```
Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

I tried `some View` but it didn't seem to even parse.

Comment: Xcode 11 beta 6 is out and Path is fixed.

Comment: @KRH wonder if I should just delete this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS 13 beta 7 release notes say it's fixed in Xcode 11 beta 6, so we just have to wait for that to be released. Hopefully tomorrow!

From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_7_release_notes) :

Resolved Issues

Using the Path structure no longer causes your app to crash if you’re using the SDKs included in Xcode 11 beta 6 and later. (53523206)

Answer (score 0):

It still will crash... Path is too broken! But if you are curious how you can get to compile successfully, you can do something like this:

```swift
struct MyShape: View {
    @State private var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { (geometry) -> AnyView in
            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
            return AnyView(Path(path).fill(Color.purple))
        }
    }
}
```

***It will crash on Path(path)***

Comment: We can only speculate, and there's no much point in it. Apple has recognized that Path is broken in beta 5, but I quote from their release notes: *Using the Path structure may cause your app to crash*. "may" being the operative word here. You best bet is wait for the next Xcode release, or go back to beta 4, if you can.

Comment: One reason the first snippet works and the second does not might be that, according to the latest documentation for Path - SwiftUI, typealias Path.Fill is deprecated. When I comment-out “.filled(Color.purple)”, it works again. This caught me in my own code. Although it had worked a in Xcode b4, with Xcode b5, no more. SwiftUI is literally changing under our feet and reminds me of when Swift 1 came out. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path